# How to rename multiple folders while keeping their files subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch, rename

I want to rename multiple folders and keep all files and subdirectories in tact.
Windows batch commands like `xcopy` and `move` can't handle every case<sup>*</sup>.

I set up two columns with old paths and new paths.

```
OLD PATH            NEW PATH
C:\dir1\dir3\dir7   C:\a1\a2\a3      
C:\dir1\dir4\dir8   C:\b1\b2\b3      
C:\dir2\dir5\dir9   C:\c1\c2\c3      
...
C:\dir2\dir6\dir0   C:\d1\d2\d3
```

Difficulties: More than one folder per line needs to be renamed; last listed folders like `dir7` can have multiple subdirectories; file time stamps shouldn't be modified

---

<sup>* `xcopy` can't move, it only copies. That's a problem if you haven't enough space to copy and delete big data.

The `move` command doesn't move subdirectories, only files</sup>

Comment: Was this a real question? Did you come up with your own answer within a minute? Or is it your personal "howto"?

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Okay. My bad. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple (straightforward) batchfile version would be like this:

```
call :robo "C:\dir1\dir3\dir7"   "C:\a1\a2\a3"
call :robo "C:\dir1\dir4\dir8"   "C:\b1\b2\b3"
call :robo "C:\dir2\dir5\dir9"   "C:\c1\c2\c3"
echo etc...
call :robo "C:\dir2\dir6\dir0"   "C:\d1\d2\d3"
goto:eof

:robo
robocopy %1 %2 /MOVE /E
goto:eof
```

You would need to quote the directories in case they have spaces.

For reading the directories out of a file you would do this:

`directories.txt`:

```
C:\dir1\dir3\dir7,C:\a1\a2\a3
C:\dir1\dir4\dir8,C:\b1\b2\b3
C:\dir2\dir5\dir9,C:\c1\c2\c3
C:\dir2\dir6\dir0,C:\d1\d2\d3
```

No need for quotes and separate them with a comma.
Then in the batchfile:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-2* delims=," %%A IN (directories.txt) DO (
  robocopy "%%A" "%%B" /MOVE /E
)
```

Also here... if you would like to see what robocopy does first use the `/L`.

If you have a file like this (with spaces to align the first and second column) you would need to add some code to strip the leading and trailing spaces from the directories:

Again the `directories.txt`:

```
C:\dir1\dir3\dir7\sada\asda ,  C:\a1\a2\a3
C:\dir1\dir4\dir8           ,  C:\b1\b2\b3
C:\dir2\dir5\dir9           ,  C:\c1\c2\c3
...
C:\dir2\dir6\dir0           , C:\d1\d2\d3
```

And this as batchfile:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1-2* delims=," %%A IN (directories.txt) DO (
  call :trim dir1 %%A
  call :trim dir2 %%B
  robocopy "!dir1!" "!dir2!" /MOVE /E
)
goto:eof

:trim
set trimmed=%2
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%c in ("%trimmed%") do set trimmed=%%c
for /l %%c in (1,1,100) do if "!trimmed:~-1!"==" " set trimmed=!trimmed:~0,-1!
set "%~1=%trimmed%"
goto:eof
```

Note: No error checking is done to see if the directories really exists or if only one column is filled... etc...
(but of course that could be added).

Comment: I like the second approach, I will try this